# How to modify this Javascript function to get the checked in quantity?

Tags: javascript, function

I have a Javascript function like this:

```
function isOneChecked(id) {
    var chk=document.getElementsByName(id);
    var len=chk.length;
    var flag=0;
    for(var i=0;i<len;i++) {
        if(chk[i].checked==true)
            flag=1;
    }
    return flag;
}
```

This function returns flag 1 if the checkbox is checked. I want to modify this function so that it returns the number of checkbox that is checked.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="list_session" id="{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ i.id }}" onchange="isOneChecked()" />
```

How can I do that? Thank you.

I have updated the function as suggested:

```
function onEdit() {
    if(!isOneChecked('list_session') && isOneChecked('list_session') > 1) {
        alert('Please select a file!');
        return false;
        }
        return true;
}
```

However, even if the check is greater than 1, it's not returning `please select a file`. If the box is not checked `Select a file` is shown.

Comment: Your check !isOneChecked('list_session') && isOneChecked('list_session') > 1 is wrong. it should be !isOneChecked('list_session') || isOneChecked('list_session') > 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the line from `flag=1;` to `flag++;`, then it should do what you're intending. This makes it to where the flag variable keeps track of how many checks it came across, rather than always setting it to 1.

The full function then looks like this:

```
function isOneChecked(id) {
    var chk=document.getElementsByName(id);
    var len=chk.length;
    var flag=0;
    for(var i=0;i<len;i++) {
        if(chk[i].checked==true)
            flag++;
    }
    return flag;
}
```

In response to your update:

Your conditional (`!isOneChecked('list_session') && isOneChecked('list_session') > 1`) will never be `true`.

If the function returns:

- 0, you get `!0 && 0>1`, which (since 0 evaluates to false) is `true && false`
- 1, then you get `!1 && 1>1`, or `false && false`.
- 2 or higher, then you get `!2 && 2>1`, or `false && false`.

In summary, you have to fix your conditional. You can do this by removing the `&& isOneChecked('list_session') > 1` portion. This should work:

```
function onEdit() {
    if( !isOneChecked('list_session') ) {
        alert('Please select a file!');
        return false;
    }
        return true;
}
```